Bayesian Network (gemtc)

I am trying to conduct an NMA using the R package gemtc.
I am following an example code which appears to be functional:
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)
library(readxl)
LSR<- read_excel("/life satisfaction/LSR.xlsx",sheet = "LSR")
View(LSR)
print(summary(LSR))
network <- mtc.network(LSR)
model <-mtc.model(network, type="consistency",n.chain=4,likelihood="normal",link="identity",linearModel="random")

However, when I try to use my code:
model <- mtc.model(network,likelihood = "normal",link = "identity",linearModel = "random",n.chain = 4)

I get the following error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, sel1 | sel2, columns, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected


You are much more likely to receive a useful answer if you make your example reproducible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
